# My mount script isn't working, why?

Tags: bash, scripts

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
mount | grep 'sda[1-5]'
if [ $? = 0 ]
then
  echo -e "its already mounted ! type u to unmount :\c"
  read word
  if [ $word = "u" || $word = "U" ]
   then 
     umount  /home/shady/Desktop/mountpoint1
     umount  /home/shady/Desktop/mountpoint2
      fi
 fi
if [ $? = 1 ]
then 
  mount /dev/sda1 /home/shady/Desktop/mountpoint1
  mount /dev/sda5 /home/shady/Desktop/mountpoint2
  echo -e "all mounted !!"
fi
```

its not even entering the first if statement

Comment: no no u got me wrong see the edit !! u replied so fast

Comment: Try [ $? -eq 0 ] .

Comment: it's certainly bad style. your `fi; if [ $?  1 ]; then` should certainly be `else`

Comment: @Progrock No. `$?` is always an integer.

Comment: -eq instead of = worked thanks guys you all are awesome !!!!! thanks again

Comment: @Progrock - it appears u got the answer... :) Even though there may be one or two other things... What do you do want the script to do, and what errors etc are u encountering

Comment: #!/bin/bash
mount | grep 'sda[1-5]' > /dev/null 2>1&
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
  then
    echo -e "its already mounted ! type u to unmount :\c"
    read -r word
    if [ "$word" = "u" ] || [ "$word" = "U" ]

     then 
       umount  /home/shady/Desktop/mountpoint1
       umount  /home/shady/Desktop/mountpoint2
fi 
  else
    mount /dev/sda1 /home/shady/Desktop/mountpoint1
    mount /dev/sda5 /home/shady/Desktop/mountpoint2
    echo -e "all mounted !!"
fi

Comment: this is the proper way i figured it out

Comment: You can test scripts like this by typing them into a bash shell one by one. It may help determine what line you are dealing with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's couple of issues. One `[ $? = 0 ]` should be `[ $? -eq 0 ]` because `$?` returns number, but `=` is the comparison for strings ( text). Second, use `[ $word = "u" ] || [ $word = "U" ]` or use `[ $word = "u" -o $word = "U" ]`. Read more on these options in `man test`

However, I'd suggest a simpler solution: use `udisksctl` utility instead of `media`. It's simpler and does a lot of stuff automatically for you. In fact this is the back-end for Ubuntu's default file manager, Nautilus.

For instance, if I wanted to mount `/dev/sda5`

```
  $ udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdb5                                                 
Mounted /dev/sdb5 at /media/xieerqi/0ca7543a-5463-4a07-8bbe-233a7b0bd625
```

Get info where is volume mounted:

```
$ udisksctl info -b /dev/sdb5 | awk '/MountPoints/' 
MountPoints:        /media/xieerqi/0ca7543a-5463-4a07-8bbe-233a7b0bd625
```

And here's unmounting

```
    $ udisksctl unmount -b /dev/sdb5                                               
Unmounted /dev/sdb5.
```

Comment: Perhaps this answer should be split into two?

Answer (score 3):

This line was your main problem:

```
if [ $word = "u" || $word = "U" ]
```

I've corrected the conditional, and tidied the control structure below:

```
#!/bin/bash
mount | grep 'sda[1-5]'
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "Volumes are already mounted."
  read -p  "Please type 'u' to unmount:" word
  if [ "$word" = "u" ] || [ "$word" = "U" ]
  then
     echo 'User wishes unmount.  Attempt umount here.'
  fi
else
  echo 'Volumes unmounted.  Attempt mount here.'
fi
```

See this [bash operators page](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ops.html) for examples.